# How to extract a large protected .zipx file on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I Want to extract large .zipx files that are protected so I have tried the following:

```
with fs.open("path") as d:
    zip_2015 = zipfile.ZipFile(d,'r')
    zip_2015.extractall(pwd = 'password')
    zip_2015.close()
```

but as far I know zipfile does not support zipx files so how can I do it?
Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Accessing .zipx with Python](//stackoverflow.com/q/29852100)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing .zipx with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852100/accessing-zipx-with-python)