# Can't extract .xz files with python "tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tar, xz

I need to extract some text files compressed to .xz files using python.

My code is just

```
import tarfile 

tarfile.open('file.xz')
```

But this fails with the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tarfile.py", line 1558, in open
    raise ReadError("file could not be opened successfully")
tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully
```

I have tried this on many .xz files and got the same result. The .xz files are not broken and can be opened fine with gnome archive manager.

I searched the problem and found [this bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue8978) but I'm not sure what to try now.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `tarfile.open('file.xz')`

Comment: Is a `.tar.xz` or simply a `.xz` file?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Yes it should be. My actual code had the ''

Comment: @falsetru Its just .xz

Comment: I had a similar issue and didn't find any answers on the internet, so I untar'd and retar'd the file, and that worked around the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unpack xz file with python which contains only data but no filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42079724/how-to-unpack-xz-file-with-python-which-contains-only-data-but-no-filename)

Comment: @DoktorJ Thats not the same question and it was asked years later.

Comment: @Qwertie both questions are about opening a `.xz` file with `tarfile`, and the answer is the same -- except the answer on the other one also covers Python 2.x's `backports.lzma`. Both questions explain that the files open fine in other programs, and give the same error when attempting to open with `tarfile`. Additionally, the other comes up first in searches and has more upvotes on both Q and A. Chronological order is irrelevant when flagging a dupe; I learned that one the hard way myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's not a `.tar.xz` file, but a `.xz` file, you need to use [`lzma` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/lzma.html), not `tarfile` module:

```
import lzma

with lzma.open("file.xz") as f:
    file_content = f.read()
```

To save the extracted content:

```
with lzma.open("file.xz") as f, open('extracted', 'wb') as fout:
    file_content = f.read()
    fout.write(file_content)
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I got it mixed up because [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217073/how-to-decompress-a-xz-file-which-has-multiple-folders-files-inside-in-a-singl) uses tarfile but I see they where using tar.xz

Comment: @Qwertie, Ah.. another answer by me ;)

Comment: Just one last question. How would I save the file after extracting because extractall('.') no longer works.

Comment: @Qwertie, I updated the answer to include it: Open file with "write" mode, and write the content there.